# SQL Server Create Trigger to auto update status after 2 days

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Please help me. I have a table with all my booking status, check in date, check out date. The flow is, when the booking is not paid after 2 days, the status will automatically update to 'NOT PAID'. I'm a newbie in creating trigger. Can anybody please help me. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Trigger won't help you. Creating sql job will do the work. You need to create sql job that will identify the eligible rows and change them. And then you need to schedule it to run every midnight.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do the above with a sql trigger.

You have several options;

Creating a SQL Job as @GuillermoZooby says,

or

You could make the Status column a [Computed Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx), making the column check the age.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers you are talking about are executed after an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement on a table or view. So this is not what you are looking for.

You should create Stored Procedure that checks date (I imagine you have a datetime column in the mentioned table) and when the booking is not paid after 2 days, the status field is updated to 'NOT PAID'.

Then you have to create SQL Job (service SQL Agent must be enabled and up) and when you configure schedule to run the previosuly created Stored Procedure just establish the time when you want to run the procedure. For example, once a day.